# Download xml file from URL to parse

Tags: java, jquery, xml, cross-domain, yql

I want to develop an app that parses an XML file. The file downloads when one navigates to a certain webpage. However, the xml file is not a part of the URL.

Therefore, when I tried making a webapp and used jquery and ajax to try and download it, it didn't work. I found a solution to patch the cross domain issue using yql, but since the file is not a part of the path, it didn't work.

Is there a way I can possible develop a Java applet to download the file even though its not a part of the URL?

Or can I stick to web development?

Just need some guidance.

The URL looks something like this:

https://sales.blablabla.net/qx/web/login/utilities/tixExport.jsp?&site=49151746&user=john&pass=doe&tid=ZYX2034982309482x

Comment: can you give an example? what else do i incorporate it with? pretty sure i exhausted that approach with the yql.

Comment: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php Have a look at the javascript part.

Comment: Do you have direct access to the xml content on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it on the server side using cURL if possible. If your using PHP this example would work.

```
<?php 
        // create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
            curl_close($ch); 

        // output XML to page
          header('Content-Type: text/xml');
          echo $output;
    ?>
```

You would use a jQuery AJAX request to pull in that PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must do it server side for this to work. U can download the file in the controller and serve it there like a stream.